# Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@theme/footer.html.twig" is not defined

Tags: theming

I know there are similar questions to this that have been asked but none of the solutions are working for me and I've been at this all day so I thought I'd give this a try.

I've created a sub-theme of Bartik for Drupal 9. I've copied the page.html.twig and I'm trying to include a templates/includes/footer.html.twig and nothing I have tried has worked.

1. I installed the components module and updated DB
2. Declared the following in subbartik.info.yml:

   ```
   components:
     namespaces:
       includes: includes
   ```
3. Input the following into page.html.twig

   ```
   {% include '@includes/footer.html.twig' %}
   ```

Cleared cache with drush, and I get error:

```
    Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@includes/footer.html.twig" is not defined in "sites/default/themes/custom/subbartik/templates/page.html.twig" at line 125. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey()
```

1. I've tried a relative path from web folder root

   ```
   {% include 'sites/default/themes/custom/subbartik/templates/includes/footer.html.twig' %}
   ```

Same error:

```
    Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "sites/default/themes/custom/subbartik/templates/includes/footer.html.twig" is not defined in "sites/default/themes/custom/subbartik/templates/page.html.twig"
```

2. I tried the old:

   ```
   {% include '@subbartik/includes/footer.html.twig' %}
   ```

Same error:

```
    Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@subbartik/includes/footer.html.twig" is not defined in "sites/default/themes/custom/subbartik/templates/page.html.twig"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

File structure (figured it would just be easier to take a screen shot):

[image: file system of drupal project starting at root, then web, sites, default, themes, custom, subbartik]

Comment: sites/default/themes? in drupal 9? where have you put your theme? it is not drupal 7 any more

Comment: This is a local dev environment. It's inside the web/ directory.

Comment: Can you provide your file structure?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with a screen shot of my file structure. Thanks.

Comment: Put it in web/themes/custom

Comment: Hi leymannx. Thanks for the reply but that can't be what's causing the problem. I have cloned sites from other developers running on my local machine and their custom themes are in web/sites/default/themes and the include functions work fine. Besides, when I'm done with this it has to go up to a production environment where all the folders need to be contained within the sites/default/ structure.

Answer (score 1):

There was a caching problem that had nothing to do with the template itself. Not sure exactly what happened but I turned off MAMP, did something else for awhile, came back and it was working fine. Thanks!